# How to Read each row values from datagrid in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

How to Read each row values from datagrid in Silverlight ?

i have this error

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  Message=La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet.
  StackTrace:
       à BusinessApplication4.Home.button4_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       à System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
       à System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
       à System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       à System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
       à MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
  InnerException: 


    foreach (var dgcol in dataGrid2.ItemsSource)
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you didn't specify an ItemsSource. Try iterating through the Items instead.

Comment: the itemsSorce is a query from wcf .can you give me  a exemple

Comment: Well, in that line of code, the only thing that can be null is the ItemsSource collection, unless you don't have a datagrid, of course :)